# Creating the id (unique identifier) from paragraph content in XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to create an xsl for an identifier will be extracted from the part of StatementCode tag in provided input code

The input XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LearningStandards>
    <StatementCodes>
        <StatementCode>AA.BBB-LA.K2.L.1</StatementCode>
    </StatementCodes>
    <Statements>
        <Statement>Demonstrate command of the conventions.</Statement>
    </Statements>
    <StatementCodes>
        <StatementCode>AADD.EPF-Caree.CSDA.L.4</StatementCode>
    </StatementCodes>
    <Statements>
        <Statement>Determine or clarify.</Statement>
    </Statements>
</LearningStandards>
```

The XSLT used is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="LearningStandards">
        <topic id="x1" xml:lang="en-US" outputclass="CCSSI-DITA"><title/>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </body>
        </topic>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="StatementCodes">
        <bodydiv outputclass="StatementCodes">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </bodydiv>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="StatementCode">
        <p outputclass="StatementCode">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Statements">
        <bodydiv outputclass="Statements">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </bodydiv>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Statement">
        <p outputclass="Statement">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<topic id="x1" xml:lang="en-US" outputclass="DITA">
    <title/>
    <body>
        <bodydiv outputclass="StatementCodes">
            <p outputclass="StatementCode">AA.BBB-LA.K2.**L.1**</p>
        </bodydiv>
        <bodydiv outputclass="Statements">
            <p outputclass="Statement">Demonstrate command of the conventions.</p>
        </bodydiv>
        <bodydiv outputclass="StatementCodes">
            <p outputclass="StatementCode">AADD.EPF-Caree.CSDA.L.4</p>
        </bodydiv>
        <bodydiv outputclass="Statements">
            <p outputclass="Statement">Determine or clarify.</p>
        </bodydiv>
    </body>
</topic>
```

And I need the output as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<topic id="x1" xml:lang="en-US" outputclass="DITA">
    <title/>
    <body>
        <bodydiv outputclass="StatementCodes">
            <p outputclass="StatementCode">AA.BBB-LA.K2.**L.1**</p>
        </bodydiv>
        <bodydiv outputclass="Statements">
            <p id="L.1" outputclass="Statement">Demonstrate command of the conventions.</p>    <!-- id="L.1" is the critical point -->
        </bodydiv>
        <bodydiv outputclass="StatementCodes">
            <p outputclass="StatementCode">AADD.EPF-Caree.CSDA.L.4</p>
        </bodydiv>
        <bodydiv outputclass="Statements">
            <p id="L.4" outputclass="Statement">Determine or clarify.</p>
        </bodydiv>
    </body>
</body>
</topic>
```

Please give me suggestions on this XSLT.

Comment: Can you explain the logic on how to compute the value for the id? Please also notice that `**L.1**` is not a valid value for an ID.

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind extracting "L.1" from the StatementCode? Why is it "L.1" and not "K2.L.1" or just "1", for example? It is the substring after the second-before-last full stop? Thanks!

Comment: Because we can take a part of text as id or not, we are checking if possible please give me the xslt code

Comment: It is possible to extract part of the text, probably using string functions such as "substring" or "substring-after". Although, in XSLT 1.0, if you want to do "substring after last full stop", for example, this is slightly trickier. You really need to explain the logic if you want a precise answer. Also, can you say if you can use XSLT 2.0 or not? Thank you.

Comment: We need to extract sub string form one tag environment use as a id in another tag that's why i raised question. And i can use XSLT 2.0 also.

Comment: **1.** The input that you show is not well-formed XML (has no root element). **2.** You did not answer the question regarding which substring to extract.

Comment: 1. I have edited the code in well-formed XML with root element 2.sub string which we have to extract is given with in **

Comment: That still doesn't answer the question. You are telling us WHAT the result is, we are asking HOW to get it. A single example does not provide the rule.

Comment: Please give me suggestions on this.

Comment: I have added the extra well formed code if possible give me the xslt code.
  --------Thanks

Comment: I corrected the indentation of your code samples. Your desired output has a superflouos `</body>` tag at the end. You may like to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a given `Statement` element, to get the relevant 'StatementCode` it looks like you need to do this...

```
<xsl:variable name="code" select="../preceding-sibling::StatementCodes[1]/StatementCode" />
```

To use this in an ID, you could use [Attribute Value Templates](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates)

```
<p outputclass="Statement" id="{$code}">
```

Unfortunaly, you have failed explained the logic behind why you only a particular substring from the code. Perhaps you want to get only the portion for "L." onwards? If so, the expression would be this:

```
<p outputclass="Statement" id="L.{substring-after($code, '.L.')}">
```

Or, maybe you want everything after the third full stop. As you are using XSLT 2.0, you could do it like this:

```
<p id="{replace($code, '^\w+\.\w+-\w+\.\w+\.', '')}">
```

Also, in XSLT 2.0, if you wanted to get everything after the second-from-last full stop, you can use `tokenize` (together with `string-join` to re-join the tokens with a full-stop between them)

```
<p id="{string-join(tokenize($code, '\.')[position() >= last() - 1], '.')}">
```

Try this template, which shows all four methods in action

```
 <xsl:template match="Statement">
    <xsl:variable name="code" select="../preceding-sibling::StatementCodes[1]/StatementCode" />
    <p outputclass="Statement" 
          id="{$code}" 
          id1="L.{substring-after($code, '.L.')}" 
          id2="{replace($code, '^\w+\.\w+-\w+\.\w+\.', '')}"
          id3="{string-join(tokenize($code, '\.')[position() >= last() - 1], '.')}">
       <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </p>
 </xsl:template>
```

Comment: logic behind that coding is last two letters form statement code with dot i want as an 'id' thanks eg: if statement code is AADD.EPF-Caree.CSDA.A.4 then id should be id="A.4" and if statement code is AACC.Link.Matter.K.CC.A.2 then id should be id="A.2"

Comment: if you have any suggestion on this please give me xslt code

Comment: Thanks @Tim C for your suggestion but i am new to xslt so i couldn't give the correct reply for logic now i am explaining logic behind that coding is last two letters form statement code with dot i want as an 'id' thanks eg: if statement code is AADD.EPF-Caree.CSDA.A.4 then id should be id="A.4" and if statement code is AACC.Link.Matter.K.CC.A.2 then id should be id="A.2" please give me xslt code Thanks in advance

Comment: It is the substring after the second-before-last full stop

Comment: Thank you so much @Tim C I have used the id2 format its working fine

Comment: @G.VinodKumar - I've added a fourth suggestion that may also help. See the definition `id3` in the XSLT.